# Javascript - increment value by 4.

Tags: javascript, variables, increment

I have a problem.

I need a Javascript function which increase (increment) variable value by 4, and when the variable value is 20, then set value of variable to 0 and again increment it by 4 and so on...

I think that I need for loop and if condition, but I don't know how to implement this...

Example

the result must be:

x = 0; then x = 4, x = 8, x = 12, x = 16, x = 20, x = 0, x= 4 ....

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a nested pair of loops:

```
while (true) {
    for (var x = 0; x <= 20; x += 4) {
        // use x
    }
}
```

This will be more efficient than using the mod (`%`) operator.

EDIT

From your comments, it sounds like you want to generate the sequence incrementally, rather than in a loop. Here's a function that will return a function that will generate the next element of your sequence each time you call it:

```
function makeSequence() {
    var x = 20; // so it wraps to 0 first time
    return function() {
        if (x == 20) { x = 0 }
        else { x += 4 }
        return x;
    }
}
```

You could then use it like this (among many ways):

```
var sequence = makeSequence();

// and each time you needed the next element of the sequence:

var x = sequence();
```

Comment: @ErikE - Using the modulo operator, each time through the loop involves involves an addition, a division and a subtraction. The nested loop involves only an addition (or a constant assignment each time through the outer loop).

Comment: @TedHopp is correct and this is better for performance.  I searched for a test case on jsPref and (surprise) someone has tested these two methods before.  See for yourself: http://jsperf.com/throw-away-test.  You have my upvote... just wish others would give this method more points too.

Comment: Performance is kind of irrelevant when an infinite loop will trigger the browser's "unresponsive script" message.

Comment: @nnnnnn - Well, yes. The outer loop was because OP didn't specify a terminating condition. Besides, it won't generate a browser complaint if this is inside a WebWorker. :)

Comment: Performance takes a back seat to correctness, clarity, and conciseness (in that order). Unless it is truly thousands per second, I vote for `%`.

Comment: Yes, the OP was a bit vague - some context would've helped, though a for loop was mentioned. But then if the increment should occur only in response to a mouse click or something then you wouldn't use a loop at all, you'd use either an `if` or `%`...

Comment: @ErikE - I agree with your priorities. I'd argue, though, that the output OP wants is best understood as the sequence (0, 4, ..., 20) repeated over and over again. To me, a nested loop structure more clearly represents that structure than does a single loop involving `%`. But that's just a matter of personal style; I can see how others would have the opposite view.

Comment: Sadly, you're probably right, given how few people seem to understand modulo well or ever use it.

Comment: I agree with you Ted that the nested loop represents the repeating sequence nicely, however it doesn't have a practical use in JS unless the outer loop has some eventual end condition and the `x` values are used in some larger calculation (and/or, as you say, there are WebWorkers involved somehow). If the idea is to display the changing `x` values in the page you'd need to use `setInterval()` or a `setTimeout()` "loop" or increment only in response to some event.

Comment: I need this for dojo createLine which I used it to draw a lines for hours (4h,8h,12h...) for a few days... So, this will be in other for loop which divide a div into days... below codes for me dont work... because, someone code always return 4, or return 0.... I need a function which returns a value for hour line, examole Increment(4) - where argument is value of increment, and of course, returned value must be remember because, always will be same... do you understand?

Comment: @user1562652 - I updated my answer with some code that might suit your needs.

Comment: I saw... but always return 0h

my code is:
for(var i = 0; i <= 5760; i = i + 1440){    
     if(i >= 1440 && i < 7200)
     {
      surface.createText({text:  + ". hours", align: "start" });
     }
    }

and here after "text:" I want to write 4h,8h,12h.... for every days

now return me 0h....

Comment: @user1562652 - You should only call `makeSequence()` once and then use the returned function over and over. Just put in a call to `sequence()` where you want to insert the hour values.

Answer (score 4):

This is easily solved with a combination of addition operators and modulus `%`.

```
x = 0;
//loop
x = (x+4)%24;
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/okereg/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

Following will help

```
function fnAddVal(val) {
     if (val >= 20)
            return 0;
     else
       return val+4;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple!

```
x = (x + 4) % 24;
```

Do you want an infinite loop? What?

Comment: I nned this for dojo createLine which I used it to draw a lines for hours (4h,8h,12h...) for a few days...

So, this will be in other for loop which divide a div into days...
below codes for me dont work... because, someone code always return 4, or return 0....  I need a function which returns a value for hour line, examole

Increment(4)
 - where argument is value of increment, and of course, returned value must be remember because, always will be same...

do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this for your loop:

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
int x = 0;
while ( x <= 20 ) 
{
    alert("The number is " + x)
    if ( x >= 20 ) 
    {
        x = 0;
    }
    x += 4;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will never alert x == 0.